# Decode .jpeg image from string

Tags: javascript, c++, image, base64, data-uri

In my JS script I'm receiving string with encoded image.jpeg. The image is created with OpenCV in C++:

```cpp
cv::imencode(".jpeg", rgb_img, jpeg_data);
std::string jpeg_string(jpeg_data.begin(), jpeg_data.end());
```

Then the string is passed through websocket.
In JS I have to decode that string and use as src of img tag. I tried (ChatGPT):

```js
// Create a Uint8Array from the binary data
    var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(jpeg_string.length);
    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < jpeg_string.length; i++) {
        uint8Array[i] = jpeg_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    // Create a Blob object from the ArrayBuffer
    var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'image/jpeg' });

    // Create an Object URL for the Blob
    var imageDataUri = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    img.src = imageDataUri;
```

and (Stack Overflow):

```js
const imageDataUri = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${jpeg_string}`;
img.src = imageDataUri;
```

None of this works. In the first example:

```
src = blob:http://0.0.0.0:7000/<random numbers, lowercase letters and dashes>
```

in the other one:

```
src = data:image/jpeg;base64,<uppercase letters and numbers>
```

How to display that image?
I'm working with Robot Operating System, Ubuntu 22.4 (shouldn't make a difference).

Comment: The problem is basically that HTML is text based. You can't inject binary. What I did to get around this was to use base64 encoding on images. I will testify that this works!

Comment: If you want people that know what `cv::imencode` or `jpeg_string` mean, I suggest you add the tag for that language and/or those libraries to your question.

Comment: Can you edit the image creation code?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I will have a look on that, I don't know what to do with this information (yet)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't think C++ code is important. It should be doing its job correctly, but I will edit that

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi OFC I can.

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's not about opencv though. OP got the binary contents of a valid image file. the generation of which is immaterial to the issue, which is javascript and HTML. the construction of the `data:` URI, including base64 encoding, can easily happen client-side.

Comment: if you want to stream images to a browser, there are "MJPEG" (not true mjpeg) approaches where you keep the HTTP response open and continuously send, with `multipart/x-mixed-replace` MIME type

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz ... so remove the `[opencv]` tag. However, as the accepted answer shows, it wasn't just JavaScript that solved the issue...

Comment: U right bro 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the correct way to encode your image:

```c
cv::imencode(".jpeg", rgb_img, jpeg_data);
auto *enc_msg = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(jpeg_data.data());
std::string encoded = base64_encode(enc_msg, jpeg_data.size());
```

Then, you can show your image using this:

```php
const imageDataUri = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${jpeg_string}`;
img.src = imageDataUri;
```

Comment: I am upvoting you, even though it appears that this actually won't fully solve @OP's issue (see my post)

Comment: @ControlAltDel thank you, anyway i'm a bit confused now. The original question refers to a single image sent through websocket, now we're talking about a video (and this would be a total different approach). Seems that DR4NKR1D3R should use a "streaming" approach, but it's way more complicated than this and it doesn't refer to this question

Comment: IMO @OP should accept your answer for answering the question s/he asked, then post another question for what they really want.

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi I want to clarify. I'm using ROS, it's a software to control robots etc and Gazebo, that is a simulation software. In Gazebo I'm simulating camera. Camera returns me an image (ROS message type) every frame. So sending image to browser seems like simplest (but I see now and before that it isn't good) approach. There were ROS packages that creates webserver with camera POV, but they are no longer maintained.

Comment: Streaming video would be great, but I'm not capable of doing that (I couldn't encode jpeg with opencv), so I will settle for that. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'd be grateful if you could give me some keywords that I should be interested in if I tried

Comment: there is no reason to transfer the image itself in base64. HTTP is perfectly happy to carry binary data. the issue is how to turn it into base64 and make a `data:` URI from it on the browser. not an issue with opencv.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code below looks like it's almost right:

```
const imageDataUri = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${jpeg_string}`;
img.src = imageDataUri;
```

The problem appears to be that the server is not base64 encoding.

Comment: What should I do? I'm hosting that server locally with PythonSimpleHTTP if i remember correctly. Should I use more advanced server (Django) and send images as response? Is there any way to make that images appear with existing server? 
BTW I don't really want to send singular image. I want to send 30 images per second to make video

Comment: @DR4NKR1D3R I would advise against trying to send 30 images a second; it'll likely be too expensive in terms of processing time. Instead, you need to create an MP4 video stream.

Comment: the server need not encode to base64 at all. this can be done client-side. not an issue with opencv.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
I used marked solution. To make it work I stole some code from other topic:

```cpp
static const std::string base64_chars =
             "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
             "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
             "0123456789+/";


static inline bool is_base64(unsigned char c) {
  return (isalnum(c) || (c == '+') || (c == '/'));
}

std::string base64_encode(unsigned char const* bytes_to_encode, unsigned int in_len) {
  std::string ret;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  unsigned char char_array_3[3];
  unsigned char char_array_4[4];

  while (in_len--) {
    char_array_3[i++] = *(bytes_to_encode++);
    if (i == 3) {
      char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
      char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
      char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
      char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 0x3f;

      for(i = 0; (i <4) ; i++)
        ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[i]];
      i = 0;
    }
  }

  if (i)
  {
    for(j = i; j < 3; j++)
      char_array_3[j] = '\0';

    char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
    char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
    char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
    char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 0x3f;

    for (j = 0; (j < i + 1); j++)
      ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[j]];

    while((i++ < 3))
      ret += '=';

  }

  return ret;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a stream of images to a browser, a common and simple solution is to to declare `multipart/x-mixed-replace` MIME type in the HTTP response, then keep sending pictures from the server in the same HTTP response.

This will require complex logic on the HTTP server side if you expect more than one client to read that video feed.

If you're already working with websockets, perhaps stick to that. It's cleaner. The server side can deal with websockets in smarter ways.

---

There is good reason to send the original binary instead of the base64 encoding because base64 blows the data up by a factor of 8/6, i.e. adding 33%. You could hope for any transparent gzip compression to catch that.

There is no reason to base64-encode the binary data on the server. HTTP is happy to carry binary data. Clientside Javascript can turn the binary file into a base64-encoded `data:` URI.

With the right APIs (`createObjectURL` from `Blob` or `File`?), the base64 encoding may *not even be needed*. The browser *might* just wrap the binary data in an "Object URL" that does not contain base64 at any point, yet is well digested by the HTML rendering. Base64 would be an implementation detail you need not think about.